# Angular Microfrontend - Need to add forcible change detection for view to refresh when plugged in

Tags: angular, angular7, web-component, angular9, angular-changedetection

We have the following tech stack -
Angular Microfrontend library - Angular 9
Host UI Angular Repo - Angular 7

Currently, when we run the micro frontend independently then on component variable changes view gets refreshed.
But when we plug into the host UI by adding it as a component -
<app-if-webcomponent *ngIf="appconfigData && isSupportedIfType" [appconfigData]="appconfigData" [userServObject]="userServObject" [imagingFabricPayload]="imagingFabricPayload$ | async" [hasAnnotationRights]="hasAnnotationPermission"> 
Then we get issues that the component variable change does not reflect in a change in view internally
and we have to add for it to pick up changes -
this.changedetection.detectChanges();

But this at times greatly affects the UI performance - e.g. if code runs in 10 ms - then it can shoot up to 20seconds as well for a component.
From our observations - we checked if its in Angular Zone or not & found that it is in NgZone - since that's a common reason for it to not be refreshed.
One of the places it doesn't work is as follows -

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.setEditAnnotationValidation();
const getValSubscription: Subscription = this.sharedService.getValue()
.subscribe((data) => {

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data = data.filter(v => v.annotationType !== ANNOTATION_TYPES.GROUP_LABEL);
    this.annotationObject = data;
  } else {
    // Other business logic
  }
  console.log('IS INA NGZONE' , NgZone.isInAngularZone());
// Had to add maual change detection
  this.changedetection.detectChanges();
  this.annotationObjectCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.annotationObject));
  this.subscriptionList.push(getValSubscription);
});
```

Please help us in knowing what could be a possible reason for it getting broken & how we could eliminate the extra overhead of putting change detection manually